# Why is this giving me a bounds error?

Tags: java

I have a custom "Heap" class:

```
public class Heap<T extends Comparable<T>>
{
    ArrayList<T> heapList;


    public Heap()
    {
        heapList = new ArrayList<T>();

    }
```

and a custom "Process" class:

```
public class Process {
    private int processID, timeUnitsRequired, priority, timeOfArrival;

    public Process(int processID, int timeUnitsRequired, int priority, int timeOfArrival) {
        this.processID = processID;
        this.timeUnitsRequired = timeUnitsRequired;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.timeOfArrival = timeOfArrival;
    }
```

But if I try to make a new Heap of Processes, like `Heap<Process> processHeap = new Heap<Process>();` I get the following error:

> Bound mismatch: The type Process is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter > of the type Heap

Why is this? I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process object needs to implement the `Comparable` interface.

**Example Implementation Comparing by Priority**

```
public class Process implements Comparable<Process>{

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Process p2 = (Process) o;
        if(this.priority > p2.priority){
          return 1;
        }else if(this.priority < p2.priority){
          return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

[Comparable API Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

Comment: You should make it `Comparable<Process>`.

Comment: that is one solution. he asked for the source of the error :-)
the other way to correct it is to remove that extends Comparable <T> (as long it is not needed at all)

Answer (score 2):

Process does not implement Comparable